# What kinds of devices appear under the \\.\PHYSICALDRIVEx path on Windows?

Tags: windows

What kinds of devices appear under the \.\PHYSICALDRIVEx path on Windows?

As far as I know only the built in hard drives are there. 
But cannot find the source I read it from - I may be wrong.

UPDATE:

Ok, changed the title, because it was a bit misleading. I'm not looking for the way to list them, but I want to know which kinds of devices Windows assigns device names like this to.

Answer (score 1):

WMI - [Win32_DiskDrive class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> The Win32_DiskDrive WMI class **represents a physical disk drive** as seen
>   by a computer running the Windows operating system. Any interface to a
>   Windows physical disk drive is a descendent (or member) of this class.
>   The features of the disk drive seen through this object correspond to
>   the logical and management characteristics of the drive. In some
>   cases, this may not reflect the actual physical characteristics of the
>   device. Any object based on another logical device would not be a
>   member of this class.

POWERSHELL:

PS > Get-Wmiobject Win32_Diskdrive

[image]

Comment: Updated the question. So all these 3 devices are built in disk drives (or appear like that for Windows)?

Comment: yes, all three are builtin on my laptop, one hdd and 2 readers